# Building multiple executables in the default Haskell Stack project

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, hpack

I used the default `stack new` to setup a project that has a server and a client as separate executables. I altered the `package.yaml` file in what seems like the right way (As of April 21, 2020 "[There is no user guide](https://github.com/sol/hpack#there-is-no-user-guide)") and added a new file to my `app` directory called `Client.hs`.

I got an error saying "Enabling workaround for Main module 'Main' listed in 'other-modules' illegally!"

How do I have stack build both the client and the server?

When I ran `stack build` I got:

```
[... clip ...]
Building executable 'ObjectServer' for ObjectServer-0.1.0.1..
[4 of 4] Compiling Client
Linking .stack-work\dist\29cc6475\build\ObjectServer\ObjectServer.exe ...
Warning: Enabling workaround for Main module 'Main' listed in 'other-modules'
illegally!
Preprocessing executable 'Client' for ObjectServer-0.1.0.1..
Building executable 'Client' for ObjectServer-0.1.0.1..
[3 of 3] Compiling Client

<no location info>: error:
    output was redirected with -o, but no output will be generated
because there is no Main module.


--  While building package ObjectServer-0.1.0.1 using:
      D:\HaskellStack\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_3.0.1.0_ghc-8.8.3.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\29cc6475 build lib:ObjectServer exe:Client exe:ObjectServer --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

The relevant portion of `package.yaml` looks like this:

```
executables:
  ObjectServer:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - ObjectServer
  Client:
    main:                Client.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - ObjectServer
```

Comment: Maybe you should put the `Client.hs` in a separate directory, such as `source-dirs:  anotherapp`.

Comment: [This example][https://github.com/hspec/sensei/blob/master/package.yaml] would seem to indicate that separate directories is not the whole answer.

Comment: In the `stack` docs, It said that you need you place each main in a separate dir, and specify them in the `stack.yaml` file. https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#multi-package-projects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems here.  First, the default value for `other-modules` in `hpack` is "all modules in `source-dirs` except `main` and modules mentioned in a `when` clause".  If you look at the generated `.cabal` file, you'll see that as a result of this default, each executable has incorrectly included the other executable's module in its `other-modules` list.  Second, the `main` setting gives the source file that contains the main module, but doesn't change the name of the module expected by GHC from `Main` to anything else.  Therefore, that *module* still needs to be named `module Main where ...`, not `module Client where...`, unless you also, separately add a `-main-is Client` GHC option.

So, I would advise modifying `Client.hs` to make it the `Main` module:

```
-- in Client.hs
module Main where
...
```

and then specifying `other-modules: []` explicitly for both executables:

```
executables:
  ObjectServer:
    main:                Main.hs
    other-modules:       []
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - ObjectServer
  Client:
    main:                Client.hs
    other-modules:       []
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - ObjectServer
```

That seems to work in my testing.