# module ‘main:Main’ is defined in multiple files - but they're the same file

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, hpack

I start a new stack project with `stack new demo` and define a second file `Other.hs` in the apps folder. There are no dependencies, just:

```
module Other where

main :: IO ()
main = print 4
```

And in `package.yaml` under `executables` I add

```
  other-exe:
    main:                Other.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - debug-multiple-files
```

Now when I do `stack build` I get:

```
<no location info>: error:
    output was redirected with -o, but no output will be generated
because there is no Main module.
```

So I add `-main-is` to ghc-options:

```
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    - -main-is Other
```

Now `stack build` works, but on `stack-ghci`, after selecting one of the executables I get:

```
<no location info>: error:
    module ‘main:Main’ is defined in multiple files: /home/.../demo/app/Main.hs
                                                     /home/.../demo/app/Main.hs
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: Ugh. This seems like a shortcoming with stack; `main: Other.hs` really ought to be enough for it to know that it needs to pass `-main-is Other.hs` on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61393123
adding `other-modules: []` to each executables block helps.
So the final block would be:

```
  other-exe:
    main:                Other.hs
    other-modules:       []
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    - -main-is Other
    dependencies:
    - demo
```